# Using Lambda and forEach to find an Object in a Set and triggering a boolean

Tags: java, foreach, lambda, java-8

Say I have this class

```
    public class MovieCharacter {

    private String name;

    public String getName() { return name ; }
    public String setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
    }
```

I'm running a test and have a Set and I want to use a Lambda to comb through each object to see if it contains a desired String for the Name. If the name is found, a boolean is tripped to "true". After it's found, I don't want the boolean changed again.

```
Set<MovieCharacter> mySet // assume this Set has previously been created and 
                     // contains 1,000's of MovieCharacter

boolean hasName = false;
mySet.forEach( i -> i.getName().equals("Darth Vader")) // add here?
assertTrue(hasName);
```

I know I'm close, but how would I finish the lambda line off so that if the set contains a MovieCharacter where .getName() returns "Darth Vader" the boolean would then get set to true? But if the the item of i under examination doesn't, it just keeps moving along?

Thanks!

Comment: It's a bad idea to name your class the same as a class from the JDK, *especially* from the automatically imported `java.lang` package.

Comment: That is a great point, I'm going to change it. It's something different in my actual program thankfully. Note for anyone reading this later - MovieCharacter used to just be Character.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23004921/how-to-check-if-element-exists-using-a-lambda-expression

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behavior you're describing is exactly what the [`anyMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) method is designed for:

```
boolean hasName = mySet.stream().anyMatch(c -> c.getName().equals("Darth Vader"));
```

Comment: Or the (IMHO funkier) lambda-free `mySet.stream().map(Character::getName).anyMatch("Darth Vader"::equals);`

Comment: Would I still want to use this if I know my set would have one and only one match?

Comment: @Mureinik's answer worked perfectly, clear and concise, thank you! I may have to use this with a million items one day, would using paralellStream require any differences?

Comment: @NateH06 just drop `parallelStream()` in there instead of `stream()` and you're done. Note, however, that the underlying collection may return a sequential stream for it, so some testing is advisable.

Comment: @NateH06 if you want exactly one, go with `.stream().filter(c -> c.getName.equals("Darth Vader")).count() == 1`

Comment: Thank you, that's great. The findFirst() way below described by @marknorkin would also work. However, I prefer your way, because I don't have to finagle some way of detecting the Optional returned as empty and connecting the boolean to it.

Answer (score 1):

What you need here is filtering operation with combination of `findFirst()` which returns `Optional`.

If you sure that there is such item in your set, then you may safely call `get()` after `findFirst()`, but in general I advice you to provide a default value using `orElse` or throw exception using `orElseThrow` on that `Optional` or use one of other useful methods. Choose wisely what fits your case :)

```
set.stream()
   .filter(character -> character.getName().equals("Darth Veider"))
   .findFirst()
```

Comment: From my understanding of the JavaDoc, this example would return Optional<Character>.

Comment: @NateH06 Yes, it will. Didnt I covered this in answer ? Would you need more claryfiyng ?

Comment: sorry, I did not intend for that comment to be posted. I had written something, figured it out before finishing the comment, and something with my browser wouldn't let me delete it, and I guess it posted. Safe to ignore.